# Python skipping functions

Tags: python, function

I have created the below code to grid an XYZ file to GeoTIFF using Python.

However, when I run the code it seems to be skipping my functions within the class.
I tried print statements within them and they were ignored.

The file is ran with no errors either. Where I am going wrong?

```
import sys
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from datetime import datetime
from osgeo import gdal


class gdal_toolbox:

    ## CONSTANTS ##

    ## API handling Globals ##
    gdal_types = [  'GDT_Unknown','GDT_Byte','GDT_UInt16','GDT_Int16',\
                    'GDT_UInt32','GDT_Int32','GDT_Float32','GDT_Float64',\
                    'GDT_CInt16','GDT_CInt32','GDT_CFloat32','GDT_CFloat64',\
                    'GDT_TypeCount' ]
    jobDict = {}
    xyz_dict = {}
    layerJson = {}
    msk = {}

    def __init__( self, kwargs ):

        if self.jobDict['no_data'] is None:
            self.jobDict['no_data'] = -11000
        else:
            self.jobDict['no_data'] = int(self.jobDict['no_data'])
        
        if self.jobDict['gridAlgorithm'] is None:
            self.jobDict['gridAlgorithm'] = 'nearest:radius1=2.25:radius2=2.25:nodata=' + str(self.jobDict['no_data'])


    def normalizeToCsv( self, xyzS3Obj ):
            MAX_POINTS = 64000000

            try:
                
                # Read in ungridded data
                self.df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Public/FLX_2020_10_AgitationTrial_OSGB_Average_1m_20201023_clip.xyz', sep='\s+|,|:|\t',header=None, engine='python')

                cnt = self.df.shape[0]
                if(cnt > MAX_POINTS):
                    raise ValueError('Maximum number of points (' + str(cnt) + ' > ' + str(MAX_POINTS) + ') in datasource exceeded')


                # convert to named x,y,z columns
                print(str(datetime.now()) + ' normalizeToCsv: to_csv (start)')
                self.df.to_csv(self.csv_buf,sep=',',header=['x','y','z'],index=None)
                self.csv_buf.seek(0)
                print(str(datetime.now()) + ' normalizeToCsv: to_csv (end)')

                dfsize = sys.getsizeof(self.df)
                print('df (1) size : ' + str(dfsize))
                #return df
                
            except Exception as e:
                self.logException(e)
                raise 
            

    def csvToTiff(self):

            try:
                x = self.xyz_dict['xAxis'] / self.xyz_dict['xCellSize']
                y = self.xyz_dict['yAxis'] / self.xyz_dict['yCellSize']
        
                no_data = str(self.jobDict['no_data'])

                if self.jobDict['srs'] is not None:
                    srs = self.jobDict['srs']
                elif self.jobDict['wkt'] is not None:
                    srs = rasterio.crs.CRS.from_wkt(self.jobDict['wkt'])

                option = gdal.GridOptions(format = 'GTIFF', outputType = gdal.GDT_Float32,  width = x, height = y, \
                    outputBounds = [self.xyz_dict['minX'], self.xyz_dict['minY'], self.xyz_dict['maxX'], self.xyz_dict['maxY']], \
                    outputSRS = srs, algorithm=self.jobDict['gridAlgorithm'])
        
                self.ds_tif = gdal.Grid('C:/Users/Public/flx_grid_gdal.tif', self.ds, options = option)
                
            except Exception as e:
                self.logException(e)
                raise
```

Comment: Did you create an instance of your class and call your functions? When you define a function it is not run automatically. You have to call a function, passing any required arguments. And when functions are defined inside a class, you must create an instance of the class and call it's methods using dot notation e.g. `class.method()` or call them in the `__init__()` method.

Comment: Python is not skipping the functions (class methods), you have not created an instance of you class or called any of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

As others have written in comments, if what you've posted is your entire script, then the script should be expected to do nothing.  It defines a class, but never instaniates an object of that class (and never goes the next step of calling any of the functions on an instantiated object of that class).

At the very least, you may need to add something **like** the following at the end of your script without any indentation (ie, not within the class):

```py
gtb = gdal_toolbox()
gtb.normalizeToCsv()
gtb.csvToTiff()
```

NB:  It looks as though your `normalizeToCsv()` function expects an argument (`xyzS3Obj`), but the function does nothing with the argument (parameter), so something is wrong there.  Either don't include the `xyzS3Obj` parameter, or do something with it.  I my suggested code above, I excluded the parameter, but it will not run like that, because the class function expects a parameter.

Comment: By convention, it's also good practice for class names to start with a capital letter, not a lower case letter.  Not compulsory, though.